# Excel: Return 4th Value , given 3 columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So one Table need to find in another sheet Table and match
Date , Type and a fixed word "RPE" , if so show me the number in  the row

Table i.e

| data | type | metric | value |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/10/2000 | bike | RPE | 4 |  |
| 11/05/2021 | row | null | null |  |
| 04/08/2022 | run | Time | 50 |  |

etc....

Table how will pull data , In other words, it searches only for the "RPE" metric, which coincides with the "Type" and "Date" and places the value .

Those that  have a "a blankl cell" value, or are of a different metric than "RPE", are ignored.

| data | type | RPE |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/10/2000 | bike | 4 |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

My actual formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--('[Ciclicos Tabela.xlsx]Ciclico tabela (2)'!$C$2:$C$9236=B2);--('[Ciclicos Tabela.xlsx]Ciclico tabela (2)'!$B$2:$B$9236=A2);--('[Ciclicos Tabela.xlsx]Ciclico tabela (2)'!$D$2:$D$9236="RPE");'[Ciclicos Tabela.xlsx]Ciclico tabela (2)'!$E$2:$E$9236)
```

I tried already

`With If´s , VLOOCKUP and INDEX/MACTH`, all without success.

**UPDATE**

I tried another two formulas both without success:

```
=INDEX('Ciclicos Tabela.xlsx'!Table1[@Valor];MATCH(1;('Ciclicos Tabela.xlsx'!Table1[@Date]=B:B)*('Ciclicos Tabela.xlsx'!Table1[@Type]=A:A)*('Ciclicos Tabela.xlsx'!Table1[@Metrica]="RPE");0))
```

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(;MATCH(1;('[Ciclicos Tabela.xlsx]Ciclico tabela'!C12=B12)*('[Ciclicos Tabela.xlsx]Ciclico tabela'!B12=A12)*('[Ciclicos Tabela.xlsx]Ciclico tabela'!D12="RPE");0);4);"")
```

Comment: Please try to put the input data using table markdown format, you can use for example: [Markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). In a way we can identify the input and the expected output on each case.

Comment: Does "04/78/20" stand for the 20th April of the year 1978 or 2078? This is the weirdest date format I've ever seen :-)